# How to add prefix 0s in an array?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program that trims an array of numbers to length 10. If the array is shorter than 10, then the program should prefix the array with 0s until it is length 10.

**Example:**

> ```
>      1234567890 :: 1234567890
>
>      12345678990:: 1234567899  
>
>      1234       :: 0000001234
> ```

```
    int[] aa= new int[]{123456789};
    if(aa.length==10)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=aa.length;i++)
        {
             system.out.println(aa[i]);
        } 
    }
    if(aa.length>0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            system.out.println(aa[i]);
        }
    }
    if(aa.length<10)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            system.out.println(aa[i]);
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: *please correct my code* what did you try? you already know that if you have a <10 case you need 10-n slots of the first array to be 0... how would you go about coding that?

Comment: This should not be solved with an array but with a string, get input as string and then use methods from the String class to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

First of all, arrays of dynamic size makes me think you want to do an ArrayList, not an array. Still, if for some reason you are dealing with actual arrays of different length, it will be something like this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lessThanTen = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        int[] newArr = new int[10];

        int numZeros = 10 - lessThanTen.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i < numZeros) {newArr[i] = 0;}
            else {newArr[i] = lessThanTen[i - numZeros];}
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, an `int` can't have more than 10 digits so I am going to presume you are using `longs`.

1. To determine the number of digits in any integral number, use `Math.log10()`.
2. If the number has <= 10 digits, use the `printf` specifier of `%010d` which allows for a field of 10 digits, padded on the left with 0's.
3. Otherwise, convert to a string and print the first 10 digits using String.substring();

```java
      for (long n : new long[] { 123,12,1, 1234579911111L, 1234567890
      }) {
         if (Math.log10(n) <= 10) {
            System.out.printf("%010d%n", n);
         }
         else {
            System.out.printf("%s%n", Long.toString(n).substring(0, 10));
         }
      }
```

The above prints the following:

```
0000000123
0000000012
0000000001
1234579911
1234567890
```

If you are reading in the values as strings, then you can just do the following.

1. If the string is greater >= 10 characters, take the substring of the first 10.
2. If the string is less < 10, then pad on the left with zeroes, as required.

```java
      for (String s : new String[] {
            "123", "12", "1", "1234579911111", "1234567890"
      }) {
         int len = s.length();
         String n = len >= 10 ? s.substring(0, 10)
               : "0000000000".substring(len, 10) + s;
         System.out.println(n);
      }
```

The above prints the following:

```
0000000123
0000000012
0000000001
1234579911
1234567890
```

Answer (score 2):

An integer cannot have 10 digits, use a `long` instead. Also, use string to solve the problem rather than arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cmdScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    long num = cmdScanner.nextLong();
    String input = String.valueOf(num);
    if (input.length() > 10) {
        System.out.println(input.substring(0, 10));
    } else {
        final int zerosToAppend = 10 - input.length();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < zerosToAppend; i++) {
            sb.append("0");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.append(input));
    }
    cmdScanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by simply writing this program:-

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int newarray[] = new int[10];
        //If it is smaller than 10
        if(arr.length<10)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<(10-arr.length);i++)
            {                       
                newarray[i] = 0;
            }
            for(int i=(10-arr.length);i<10;i++)
            {
                newarray[i] = arr[i-(10-arr.length)];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {               
                newarray[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newarray));
    }
}
```

Hope this will Help